# Npm ERR! Maximum call stack size

Tags: npm

Been trying to create a project for over twenty-four hours now using the following commands

- create-react-native-app
- react-native init
- expo init

but getting this same error and completely stuck...

```
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-13T07_43_16_688Z-debug.log
[08:43:17] Process exited with non-zero code: 1
[08:43:17] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Comment: Have you checked the complete log? Have you set `EXPO_DEBUG=true` in the env?

Comment: I don't actually know how to set that, any hint?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+set+env+variables

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll check it out

Comment: I've set EXPO_DEBUG=true but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Probably i don't know your specific project. Try to delete node_modules folder and install again with `npm install`

Comment: Just did that but end up with the same thing